# Function if/elif/else syntax error

Tags: function, python-3.x, if-statement

I can't figure out why I am getting a syntax error for this function I wrote. It occurs at the first elif. When I try to run it, the error in IDLE only says "invalid syntax" then highlights 'elif'.

The Code:

```
def sort(count_dict, avg_scores_dict, std_dev_dict):
    '''sorts and prints the output'''
    menu = menu_validate("You must choose one of the valid choices of 1, 2, 3, 4 \n        Sort Options\n    1. Sort by Avg Ascending\n    2. Sort by Avg Descending\n    3. Sort by Std Deviation Ascending\n    4. Sort by Std Deviation Descending", 1, 4)
    print ("{}{0:27}{0:39}{0:51}\n{}".format("Word", "Occurence", "Avg. Score", "Std. Dev.", "="*51))

    if menu == 1:       
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(word_average_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=False))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{}{0:27}{0:39:.4f}{0:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key])

    elif menu == 2:
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(word_average_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{}{0:27}{0:39:.4f}{0:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key])

    elif menu == 3:
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(std_dev_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=False))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{}{0:27}{0:39:.4f}{0:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key])

    elif menu == 4:
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(std_dev_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{}{0:27}{0:39:.4f}{0:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key])

    return None
```

Also, does my print formatting look correct? It's supposed to justify over right so many spaces and the last 2 are floats to the 4th decimal place.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's a typo. You're not closing the last parenthesis on the print statement at line 9.

Comment: you sir, are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're entering a blank line in between the start of every elif.

Try this:

```
def sort(count_dict, avg_scores_dict, std_dev_dict):
    '''sorts and prints the output'''
    menu = menu_validate("You must choose one of the valid choices of 1, 2, 3, 4 \n        Sort Options\n    1. Sort by Avg Ascending\n    2. Sort by Avg Descending\n    3. Sort by Std Deviation Ascending\n    4. Sort by Std Deviation Descending", 1, 4)
    print ("{}{0:27}{0:39}{0:51}\n{}".format("Word", "Occurence", "Avg. Score", "Std. Dev.", "="*51))

    if menu == 1:       
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(word_average_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=False))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{}{0:27}{0:39:.4f}{0:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))
    elif menu == 2:
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(word_average_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{}{0:27}{0:39:.4f}{0:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))
    elif menu == 3:
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(std_dev_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=False))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{}{0:27}{0:39:.4f}{0:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))
    elif menu == 4:
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(std_dev_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{}{0:27}{0:39:.4f}{0:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))
    return None
```

Comment: was a simple typo. fixed it.

Comment: @ryandoucette Awesome! If this answer worked, please accept this answer. Thanks! :)